# Replace NaN with Null of a very long string in Matlab

Tags: sql, matlab

I have a very long string, I'd like to find all the NaN values and replace it 'Null'. This long string was converted from a 120 x 150000 cell. The reason for converting it into a long string was I was going to convert it into a one giant SQL query as fastinsert and datainsert can can be very slow and sometimes I'm running out of heap space. The idea is to do the following

```
exec(sqlConnection, long_string)
```

I tried using the regexpreop to replace NaN with null but it seems very slow. Is there an alternative way.

```
long_string = regexprep(long_string,'NaN','null');
```

Comment: Are there any delimiters in the string- are you sure that `NaN` is always what you want to replace?

Answer (score 5):

As Floris mentioned `regexp` is a very strong command and as a result is slower than other find commands.

In addition to Floris suggestion you can try using `strrep` which works in your case, since you are not using any of the special powers of `regexp`.

Here is an example:

```
str = char('A' + rand(1,120 * 15000)*('z'-'A'));

tic
str2 = strrep(str, 'g', 'null');
disp('strrep: '), toc

tic
str3 = regexprep(str, 'g','null');
disp('regexprep: '), toc
```

On my computer it will return:

```
strrep: 
Elapsed time is 0.004640 seconds.
regexprep: 
Elapsed time is 4.004671 seconds.
```

Comment: +1 for three things: the suggestion of `strrep`, the timing example, and the awesome way of generating a random string of characters!! The timing varies a LOT with length of string, it appears... (longer goes faster - go figure).

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Really helpful stuff.

Comment: @Floris: Thank you! @user1796228: You can also think of using parallel computing(such as `parfor`) when you split your data.

Answer (score 2):

`regex` is very powerful, but can be slow because of its flexibility. If you still have the original cell array - and assuming it contains only strings - the following line of code should work, and very fast:

```
cellArray{find(ismember(cellArray,'NaN'))} = 'null';
```

`ismember` finds all the elements in `cellArray` that are `NaN`, returning a boolean array with the same shape as `cellArray`; the `find` operation turns these into indices of the elements that are `NaN`, and then you just assign the value `null` to all of them.

It must be said that 120 x 150,000 is a VERY large cell array - it will occupy over 2 GB even with just a single character in each cell (I know this because I just created a 120x15000 cell array, and it was 205,500,000 bytes). It might be worth processing this in smaller chunks rather than all at once. Especially if you know that the `NaN` would occur only in some of the columns, for example.

Processing a GB sized string, especially when you can't operate in-place (you are changing the size of the string with every replacement, and it's getting longer, not shorter)  is going to be dead slow. It's possible you could write a short `mex` function to do this if you really have no other option - that could be pretty fast.

Comment: Actually it has both strings and numeric. I think I will go for splitting the cell into smaller chunks and process that instead.